# CSS remove border-top's part

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to cut top border's part in css?
for example:

[image: example]

Comment: please write some of your HTML

Comment: Use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for that

Comment: Easiest way is for the "About Us" box to have no bottom border (or a white one) and be on top of the submenu by exactly one pixel.

Answer (score -1):

What you could do:

`ABOUT US` button:

```
border-bottom:1px solid white;
position:relative;
z-index:11
```

Sub menu:

```
margin-top:-1px;
z-index:10;
```

That should work.

Comment: Don't you mean `margin-top: -1px;`? You would be pushing it away form the border. Instead you want it under it right?

Comment: You are right, was a little bit too quick.